# Reverse for 'post_comment' with keyword arguments '{'kwargs': {'pk': 1}}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/\\Z']

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have this comment section that allows users to comment, but the problem I have is that I want users to stay on the same page after commenting. And that is giving me a headache about how to go about it.
I wanted to redirect using 'post-detail," but because I have a slug in there, it doesn't work. The second option is to use "post_comment," and this is the error I'm getting. I need to redirect either by using post-detail or post_comment.

models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
   #username = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True,unique=True, blank=True)  # remove the username field
   email = models.EmailField(_("email address"), unique=True) # make email field required and unique
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   profile_image = models.ImageField(max_length=100, upload_to=get_profile_image_filepath, null=True, default=get_default_profile_image)
   location = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
   date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="date joined", auto_now_add=True)
   is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   is_supperuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)


 
   USERNAME_FIELD = "email"  # set this field which defines the unique identifier for the User model to "email"
   REQUIRED_FIELDS = [] 

   objects = CustomUserManager()  # specify that all objects for the class come from the CustomeUserManager

   def __str__(self) -> str:
      return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_login}"

   def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
      return self.is_admin

   def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
      return True



class Post(models.Model):
     class Status(models.TextChoices):
         DRAFT = 'DF', 'Draft'
         PUBLISHED = 'PB', 'Published'
     title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     slug =  models.SlugField(max_length=250,     unique_for_date='publish', unique=True)
     content = models.TextField()
     author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='post')
     publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
     image = models.ImageField(default="default.jpg", upload_to='post_pics')
     created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=Status.choices, default=Status.DRAFT)

     objects = models.Manager()
     published = PublishedManager()
     tags = TaggableManager()
```

views.py

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    """ show the detail of a specific post """
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'
    slug_field = 'slug'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
       context['author'] = lowercase_first_name(self.object.author)
       context['tags'] = self.object.tags.all()
       # context['comments'] = self.object.comment.all()
       context['comments'] = Comment.objects.filter(blog=self.object)
       context['pk'] = self.kwargs.get('pk')
       return context

def post_comment(request, pk):
   blog = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
   comment = Comment(
      user_comment=request.user,
      comment =request.POST['comment'],
      blog=blog)
   comment.save()
   return redirect('post_comment', kwargs={'pk': pk})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
     path('', views.post_list, name='home'),
     path('<author_slug>/<slug:slug>/<int:pk>/', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
     path('post/<int:pk>/', views.post_comment, name='post_comment'),
```

]

Comment: Unrelated, but mixing class and method based views is surely going to be confusing

Comment: Please provide the code of the `author` model. Specifically where the slug is formed, created and stored. I am talking about `author_slug` and `slug`. Somehow you use two for your `PostDetailView`

Comment: @Tarquinius I've update the models but the slug is only added to the Post model since you need the post title to be used as the slug.

Comment: This is your defined url: `'<author_slug>/<slug:slug>/<int:pk>/'`. The code you are providing right now does not tell me how you are populating the `<author_slug>`. At least I don't know or see where it comes from. But that parameter in addition to `Post.slug` is what you need to successfully reach your `PostDetailView`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the kwargs.
Do this

```
redirect('post_comment', pk=pk)
```

Or just

```
redirect('post_comment', pk)
```

Doc here [redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)

Comment: when I use redirect ('post_comment', pk) or  redirect('post_comment', pk=pk), it tells me MultiValueDictKeyError at /post/1/
'comment'. The only redirect that works for me is redirect('home') and it's wired to comment on a post and then redirect you to the home page.

Comment: Does not make sense to direct the user to that view, since it has no template connected and ends in a redirect itself. You would want to redirect to `PostDetailView`.

Comment: I thought so too, but that was the only url pattern I saw that matches the error they are describing on the title of the question, my next guess would be to check how they are submitting the comment through the template